# breeze.js how do I share metadata between 2 entity managers

Tags: javascript, entity, metadata, breeze, entitymanager

I have 2 entity managers:

```
var mgr1 = new breeze.EntityManager('api/app');
var mgr2 = new breeze.EntityManager('api/app');
```

Right now I am getting the metadata for each one separately, although the metadata is exactly the same.  I am calling the fetch method explicitly to control the timing of when the metadata is loaded.

```
mgr1.fetchMetadata();
mgr2.fetchMetadata();
```

I've read that I can share the metadata between the 2 managers but I have not found an example.  From what I've read, I think I can specify the metadata in the constructor of the 2nd manager that references the 1st manager's metadata, but not sure what that would look like.  So my code would look something like this:

```
var mgr1 = new breeze.EntityManager('api/app');
mgr1.fetchMetadata();
var mgr2 = new breeze.EntityManager({ serviceName: 'api/app', metadata: WHAT_GOES_HERE});
```

I know I will also have to sequnece this with promises so the 2nd manager isn't constructed before the 1st managers has it's metadata loaded.

Am I on the right path with this?  My goal is to eliminate the extra bandwidth to load the metadata for the 2nd manager.  thanks

Comment: Check out the samples - I believe one of them on the samples page shows a multiple entityManager configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used breeze.js before, but from what I gather from the documentation (http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityManager.html), something like this should work:

```
var mgr1 = new breeze.EntityManager('api/app');
mgr1.fetchMetadata();
var mgr2 = new breeze.EntityManager({
   serviceName: 'api/app', 
   metadataStore: mgr1.metadataStore
});
```

Of course `mgr2` should be set up after the `mgr1.fetchMetadata` promise is fulfilled, as you already say in your question.

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually have to fetch the metadata to share the same MetadataStore. The following two statements are a pretty crisp approach:

```
var em1 = new breeze.EntityManager('api/app'); 
var em2 = em1.createEmptyCopy();
```

I'm not trying to be clever. My point is that a `MetadataStore`, which is a *container* of metadata, is available immediately after `EntityManager` creation and is well defined prior to holding any metadata whatsoever.

The `createEmptyCopy()` method "clones" the manager without copying its entity cache contents. The copied attributes include the manager's `MetadataStore` and its `DataService`.

Because the managers share the same `MetadataStore`, fetching metadata with *either* manager will do the trick.

Check out the Breeze API documentation for [EntityManager](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityManager.html) and [MetadataStore](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/MetadataStore.html).

Comment: This is very interesting.  I have a use case in my app where the user is in a screen creating an "event" transaction.  The "event" is tied to a person, but the person may or may not exist.  And the DB is structured in such a way that a person cannot be created at the same time as the "event", the person record must physically exist first.  So I open a popup screen so a person can be added if necessary.  I need this second transaction to be completed entirely independent of the "event" transaction, so I need seperate entity caches.  I think the configuration you wrote above will allow that.

Comment: I was re-thinking this, and wondering if it's possible in breeze to do a "SaveChanges" but specify which entities to send to the server, while keeping the other entities in the cache for a  later "SaveChanges".  This may be a candidate for a separate question.

Comment: It is a candidate for a separate question. :-)  You may be able to answer that question yourself after reviewing the API Doc for [saveChanges](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityManager.html#method_saveChanges)

Comment: As for the scenario in your first comment, you can do this quite easily with one manager by saving the new Person independently of the other pending changes to events. Learn how to "cherry pick" entities to save ... by reviewing the [saveChanges API](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityManager.html#method_saveChanges)